# regex that works with sed not honored with ${var//search/replace}

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to simply do a regular expression replace in bash but cannot figure it out.  In my test, I would like the following string transformed:
test_data(123)
to 
test_xyz
I've tried the following:

```
 echo "test_data(123)" | sed -e 's/.*\(data(.*)\).*/xyz/g'
```

And that gets me: xyz

Then I tried:

```
var=${"test_data(123)"//.*\(data(.*)\).*/xyz}
```

But I get an error - bad substitution

How do I get my desired results on the regex replace in bash?

Comment: `${foo//...}` doesn't use regexes at all. It uses normal glob patterns (same as for filenames).

Comment: In `sed` regex `.*` means "zero or more of any character".  In a `glob` construct `*` means the same, so `.*` means a dot followed by zero or more of any character.  ("any character" excludes a newline depending n flags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${foo//$match/$replace}` uses fnmatch (glob-style) patterns, not any form compatible with BRE/ERE/PCRE or other conventional regex syntax formats.

```
input="test_data(123)"
match='data(*)'
replace='xyz'

result=${input//$match/$replace}
echo "$result"
```

...properly emits `test_xyz`.